# SSRS insert exact specific value in a cell of a Matrix using expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm not sure if my question is really stupid, but I found nothing on the internet...

Is it possible to insert a specific value in a cell of a matrix?

for example I have a dataset like below:

```
Month   Prod   Amount
  2      X       34$
  11     Y       12$
  7      Z       150$
```

and a matrix like:

```
-------|  Month    |
Prduct |SUM(Amount)|
```

So the row group are products and column group are the months of a specific year.
If I want to add an extra column, with a specific value chosen **dynamically** from the amount (for xample 150$) so to have

```
-------|  Month    |columnName
Prduct |SUM(Amount)|   150
```

is that possible? also if the value is repeated through the column (it would be useful if I wanted the new column to have this specific value added for each value)

thanks a lot!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a value directly in your matrix but it will be repeated for each record.

The best way is to add a new column with conditional values is to do this in your dataset query. Probably with a CASE statement if you are using SQL.

EDIT: If you can't adjust the query for whatever reason, you can add the new column and use SWITCH function inside your textbox to achieve the same.